# Hello world VB.NET class library, called from PHP

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, com, com-interop

Here's the AssemblyInfo.vb:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
' set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
' associated with an assembly.

' Review the values of the assembly attributes

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("ClassLibrary1")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("ClassLibrary1")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2012")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")> 

<Assembly: ComVisible(True)> 

'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid("bd484c72-e166-4480-a1fd-71ab12e09e25")> 

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'      Major Version
'      Minor Version 
'      Build Number
'      Revision
'
' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
' by using the '*' as shown below:
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

And here's the class:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub HelloWorld()
        MsgBox("hello, world")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried to access it from PHP after putting the DLL through regasm.exe.  No response.

[EDIT:  Now after running it through C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe I'm getting a strong name failure, which I'm working on now.]

Does anyone have a bare bones, Hello world sample of a .NET DLL (another word for "class library" if I'm not mistaken) that I could access through PHP 5?  And am I on the right path with this methodology thus far?

How is this done?  Thanks for any help.

This is the PHP code BTW:

```
<?php
 $obj = new COM("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
 $output=$obj->HelloWorld();
 echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Why use COM?  Why not DOTNET?

Comment: If you're talking about my PHP code at the bottom of the post, thanks!  That looks wrong (doesn't it?), and is something I never revisited after I started taking what began as a COM job more toward a .NET solution.  You're suggesting that should be DOTNET()?  What about my other code upstairs, is that okay, or should that be different?  Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Yep, I'm not expert on COM assemblies, but it seems to me that since you have a .NET project anyway, you might try and load the .NET assembly with `DOTNET`.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Comment: Thanks.  Will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be normal for PHP to be running on a web server that is running as a service -- unless you've jumped through many hoops, these **cannot interact with the desktop**, so there is nowhere for your `MessageBox` to show.